# Modules exporting identical predicates in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have a (large) number of Prolog files each of which contains a uniquely named module. All modules export the same set of predicates. Now, I would like to use the same subset of predicates from a number of these modules in a main module. How do I do this in SWI-Prolog?

This is a minimal fictitious example of what I would like to achieve.

Module a:

```
:- module(a, [f/2]).
f(0,1) :- !.
f(N,R) :- 
   N1 is N-1, 
   f(N1,R1), 
   R is N*R1.
```

Module b:

```
:- module(b, [f/2]).
f(0, 1) :- !.
f(1, 1) :- !.
f(N, R) :- 
   N1 is N - 1, 
   N2 is N - 2, 
   f(N1, R1), 
   f(N2, R2), 
   R is R1 + R2.
```

Both modules define and export a predicate f/2. Now, in a main module, I like to use both f from module a and f from module b. However, adding

```
:- use_module(a).
:- use_module(b).
```

in the main module gives an error ("No permission to redefine module").

I guess I'm looking for something similar to "qualified imports" that exists in Java, where writing a.f(8,X) and b.f(8,X) would make a difference between the two calls (a and b would be different packages then).

I know very well how to program in a number of different languages but Prolog is not one of them. It is very possible I've misunderstood something fundamental with modules in Prolog.

Comment: `:- use_module(a, []). :- use_module(b, []).`

Comment: Yes, that works - wonderful! Thanks!